# I am trying to find the url that would point to a specific ARRAY within the code for a redirect

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to find the URL string that would be used to type out so it will bring me to the redirect page, allowing it to count down then changing like expected. Would you happen to know the URL string that points to array 3?

```
//Links list
$links=array();

// All your links come here. Just copy / paste the last block, increase the index and fill it.

$links[0]['link']="http://google.com";
$links[0]['title']="We Sent You an Email";
$links[0]['pic']="";

$links[1]['link']="http://bing.com";
$links[1]['title']="we sent you an email";
$links[1]['pic']="";

$links[2]['link']="";
$links[2]['title']="";
$links[2]['pic']="";

$links[3]['link']="yahoo.com";
$links[3]['title']="We sent you an email";
$links[3]['pic']="";


// URL variables
$destination = $links[$_GET["dest"]]['link'];
$title = $links[$_GET["dest"]]['title'];
$pic = $links[$_GET["dest"]]['pic'];
if(!isset($_GET["d"])) {
$d=0;
} else {
$d=$_GET["d"];
}


echo '
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">
<title>'.$title.'</title>';
if($no_redirect != 1)
{
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="'.$d.';url='.$destination.'" />


</head>
<body>
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; margin-top: 20px;">Your request is loading, please wait.<br>If you are not redirected automatically within '.$d.' seconds, <a href="'.$destination.'">click here</a>.</p>';
if(!empty($pic)) {
echo '<p style="text-align: center;><a href="'.$destination.'"><img src="'.$pic.'"></a></p>';
}
echo '</body>
</html>
';
} else {
echo '
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
';
}

?>
```

Comment: I have read your question five times now and it's still unclear

Comment: Not clear to me too. Are you trying to find some url to get in the codition of your file? Like `mysite.com/file.php?dest=3`?

Comment: Thank you for chiming in guys. I have tried the (file.php?dest=3) and it works in terms of making the redirect happen. However that isn't what this script is intended to do..

When the script is called... the landing page is supposed to arrive and present a count down, and then the redirect happens.

This landing page also brings up an image that is pointed to within the code.

However.. the string that is provided by Felippe works, but doesn't hold the redirect for the seconds intended for the reader to consume information.

What do you think?

Comment: I found in the code that I just need to up the number within the code (if(!isset($_GET["d"])) {
$d=300;)